# Extract data from HTML file converted from Word

Tags: php, web-scraping

I need to extract data from a HTML file. In Microsoft Word I have some data that could be easily converted into HTML; I need to extract that data and insert it into an SQL table.

```
Record n.1354 - acidi_nucleici
Gli RNA sono diversi dal DNA perché                                                                                                                   
V - contengono uracile e ribosio                                                 
F - contengono uracile e timina                                                  
F - contengono uracile e desossiribosio                                          
F - contengono ribosio e timidina                                                
F - contengono ribosio e desossiribosio                                          

Record n.1417 - acidi_nucleici
Il DNA circolare si trova                                                                                                                             
V - nei mitocondri                                                               
F - nei nucleosomi                                                               
V - nei batteri                                                                  
F - nel nucleolo                                                                 
F - nel Golgi                                                                    

Record n.1418 - acidi_nucleici
Il DNA nelle cellule si trova                                                                                                                         
V - nel nucleo                                                                   
F - nei centri organizzatori microtubulari                                       
V - nei mitocondri                                                               
F - nei poliribosomi                                                             
F - nel citoplasma
```

I need to create a function that:

1. recognizes whether the line is an option or a question (i.e.
   if before the line there is "V -" or "F -" it's an option; if there
   is "Record n.*" it's the question);
2. if the line is an option, recognizes whether it is false ("F -") or true ("V -").

I thought of building the SQL table this way:

```
Column 1: id
Column 2: text
Column 3: question (0 = it's an answer; 1 = it's a question)
Column 4: relate_to (if it is an answer, relate the answer to the question ID)
Column 5: true_false (if it is an answer, is it true or false?)
```

The main problem is: I don't even know where to start! (except from using `file_get_contents` function, maybe).

Comment: You need to tell us what's your server side technology. php? .net? ruby?

Comment: oh yes, sure! It would be better in php.